# ORA-06550 and PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, unix, ora-06550, pls-00103

HI,

I am using UNIX OS and working on oracle. I am getting the error message below

```
E ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor
The symbol "" was ignored.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

On googling, I found
"The problem appears to be with Windows CRLF characters on line breaks. Oracle does not treat this as white space, instead it sees it as an empty string. In order to get round this problem, convert the CRLF characters to LF characters and Oracle should be happy."

Anyone have any idea about why it is happening in UNIX/ksh shell?

Comment: Was the script your running created on a Windows system?

Comment: Like JOTN suggests, my best guess is that this script was created on a windows system and transfered to UNIX in binary mode (which will conserve the CRLF as the line terminator instead of converting to just LF).

Comment: Please suggest what to do to overcome this

Comment: Look for a command called "dos2unix" which is on a lot of Unix systems.  It will convert that file for you.

Comment: I don't think that Windows CRLF cause this problem, at least I've never encountered it during the last 15+ years. Many people write scripts on Windows machines and run them on Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JOTN said, the dos2unix command is your friend here.  Should be invoked something like

```
dos2unix the_file_you_want_converted > another_file_to_hold_the_unix_version
```

Share and enjoy.