# Oracle SQL RETURN INTO Fails within CFQUERY (ORA-06550/PLS-00103)

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I'm trying to update a record at the same time I select it. In Oracle SQL Developer, the below query works. However, when I execute it from within a CFQUERY tag in ColdFusion, I get an error (see below). I found this stack overflow ([ORA-06550 and PLS-00103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270818/ora-06550-and-pls-00103)) but wasn't any help.

Ideally, I'd also like to return the whole record, not just the ID of the affected record. So, I have two questions.

1. Why is the below record failing from within a ColdFusion CFC's CFQUERY?
2. How to I rewrite the query to return the affected record rather than just that record's id?

   ```
   DECLARE
     record_id scpricequeue.scpricequeueid%TYPE;

   BEGIN
   update scpricequeue
   set islocked = 1, datelocked = sysdate
   where scpricequeueid = (
     select scpricequeueid
     from (
       select scpricequeueid
       from scpricequeue
       where islocked = 0 and completed = 0
       order by dateadded asc
     )
     where rownum < = 1
   )
   RETURNING scpricequeueid INTO record_id;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Locked Record: ' || record_id);

   END;
   ```

ERROR RECEIVED when executed as CFQUERY:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when
expecting one of the following: begin function package pragma procedure
subtype type use <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
form current cursor The symbol "" was ignored.*
```

Comment: Also, I should note that I removed the DBMS_OUTPUT line within the CFQUERY

Comment: Remove the space between '<' and '='.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
you can see here that, after the semicolon in declare block, CF pushed the query to the db layer, and oracle in turn replied back stating, I see a space instead of a begin keyword! Sure we have to push the block completely, and this should work.

```
<cfset variables.plsql = "
DECLARE
  record_id scpricequeue.scpricequeueid%TYPE;

BEGIN
update scpricequeue
set islocked = 1, datelocked = sysdate
where scpricequeueid = (
  select scpricequeueid
  from (
    select scpricequeueid
    from scpricequeue
    where islocked = 0 and completed = 0
    order by dateadded asc
  )
  where rownum < = 1
)
RETURNING scpricequeueid INTO record_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Locked Record: ' || record_id);

END;
"
>
<cfquery name="q" datasource="yourDSN">
    #variables.plsql#
</cfquery>
```

Set the query string as a variable, while executing anonymous `pl/sql` blocks!

**Courtesy:**  http://awads.net/wp/2005/07/25/oracle-plsql-in-cfquery/

Comment: All you're doing is moving where the SQL string is created. Be it in a variable or between the `<cfquery>` tags makes no difference. The error is coming *from the DB* not from ColdFusion, so it's not going to matter how differently you write the CFML to arrive at the same SQL string to pass to the DB.

Comment: The error comes from Oracle , yes it is,but issue i guessed is,the query is not pushed to oracle correctly, and hence the error!

Comment: @AdamCameron you can see here that, after the semicolon in declare block, CF pushed the query to the db layer, and oracle in turn replied backs tating, I see a space instead of a begin keyword! Sure we have push the block completely, and this should work!

Comment: Whether you create the string in a variable first or directly in the `<cfquery>` block is neither here nor there. CF doesn't process the string at all, it just passes it to the DB. The only difference here is that when using a variable inside a `<cfquery>` block, any embedded single quotes will be escape, so you'll be passing `''Locked Record: ''` rather than `'Locked Record: '`. And all that will achieve is causing a syntax error once the DB gets it.

Comment: Why are you even commenting on the CFML-specific side of things here? Looking at your profile you don't actually know anything about CFML!?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, thank you! Your suggestion works. The PL/SQL now executes, BUT when I dump the query variable (q in your example) I get "Variable q is undefined"

Comment: @ChrisGeirman printing the variable is not possible I beleive, trying setting `result` attribute for cfquery.

Comment: @AdamCameron I just go with basics of oracle, it is pretty much same , so far as the FE components I worked.(JDBC,pro*C,ODBC,ADO..) I don't mean to be offensive! Sorry if you felt so. Thanks.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, I have checked the result struct, but the id of the affected row seems to only be returned on insert, not update. I think I may need to figure out how to return a rowset rather than just the id. It doesn't appear the PL/SQL is passing anything back to the cfquery tag when I pass just the id of the affected row.

Answer (score 0):

Do two queries, this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883117/3112803
Hope that helps.

Since you are only doing one update and one select then the cftransaction tags are not needed.  But if you were doing multiple add/update/deletes then you would want the cftransaction tag so if a error happens they would all roll back.

Answer (score 0):

There are some db engines with which you can use a semi-colon.  These include ms-sql and mySql.  These do not include oracle.

This code runs without error:

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="burns">
select 1 record 
from dual
</cfquery>
```

But, if you add a semi-colon,

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="burns">
select 1 record 
from dual;
</cfquery>
```

You get

```
Error Executing Database Query.  
[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00911: invalid character  

The error occurred in D:\DW\dwtest\Dan\abc.cfm: line 106

104 :  --->
105 : 
106 : <cfquery name="x" datasource="burns">
107 : select 1 record 
108 : from dual;
```

Basically you need another approach.  You move your code to a stored procedure and call that from ColdFusion, or you can follow @gfrobenius's advice and use more than one cfquery.  Or you can do something else.