# Using CFQUERY and Returning a Recordset Using an Oracle Anonymous Block

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, plsql

Reference: [Oracle SQL RETURN INTO Fails within CFQUERY (ORA-06550/PLS-00103)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865054/oracle-sql-return-into-fails-within-cfquery-ora-06550-pls-00103)

Placing the PL/SQL into a variable then executing in a CFQUERY tag works, but when I dump the query variable, I get "Variable XX is undefined".

How do I get the anonymous block to return the id of the affected record, or better yet, the entire record?

Below is the code which executes, but throws the error...

```
    <cfset plsql = "
        DECLARE record_id scpricequeue.scpricequeueid%TYPE;

        BEGIN
        update scpricequeue
            set datelocked = sysdate
            where scpricequeueid = (
                select scpricequeueid
                from (
                    select scpricequeueid
                    from scpricequeue
                    where islocked = 0 and completed = 0
                    order by dateadded asc
                )
                where rownum <= 1
            )
        RETURNING scpricequeueid INTO record_id;

        END;
        ">

    <cfset sql = "
        select *
        from scpricequeue
        ">

    <cfquery name="q" datasource="ecomd">
        #plsql#
    </cfquery>

    <cfdump var="#q#">
```

**ERROR: Variable q is undefined**

Comment: You need to use the result attribute instead of name to dump the result.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Oracle, but the `name` attribute of cfquery will be populated with the first *resultset* returned by the generated sql (if any). Not all statements generate a resultset. For example, `select` statements do, but `insert/update/delete` statements do not. It does not sounds like [`RETURNING`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) actually generates a *resultset*, which would explain by `q` is undefined.

Comment: @MattBusche I thought the same thing at first, but the result attribute simply allows you to name the structure that returns things such as recordCount, executionTime, whether the query is cached, and the SQL executed. Bummer! Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @Leigh I think you're exactly right, but how do I fix this? I think the answer may be on this page http://www.orafusion.com/oracf_pls.htm in the section titled “Use Oracle referenced cursors to return result sets (ColdFusion 4.5+, Oracle 7.3+):”. So now, I'm trying to figure out how to create an oracle package and executing it as described.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman - Honestly, I have forgotten most of my Oracle ;-) What exactly does RETURNING do when run directly against the database? The description makes it sound like it *populates* something, rather than outputting or returning data. This may be way off base, but could it be as simple as you need to SELECT or OUTPUT the "thing" being populated, so the result is captured by cfquery?

Comment: @Leigh - In my case, RETURNING takes the affected record ID and populates a variable. I can verify that this working by writing to the DBMS console. Maybe I can use that to SELECT the record before END. I'll give that a try, but I was able to solve this problem in another way, but doing a SELECT...FOR UPDATE

Comment: @ChrisGeirman - *RE: populates a variable* Makes sense. You just need to add the cfquery equivalent of returning the value to the console. I think SELECT'ing the variable would do it. Anyway, glad you ultimately figured out a solution. You should write it up as an "answer", so it is more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my specific need in another way, by using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

> *When you issue a SELECT statement against the database to query some records, no locks are placed on the selected rows. In general, this is a wonderful feature because the number of records locked at any given time is kept to the absolute minimum: only those records that have been changed but not yet committed are locked. Even then, others are able to read those records as they appeared before the change (the “before image” of the data).*
>
> *There are times, however, when you will want to lock a set of records even before you change them in your program. Oracle offers the FOR UPDATE clause of the SELECT statement to perform this locking.*
>
> *When you issue a SELECT...FOR UPDATE statement, the database automatically obtains row-level locks on all the rows identified by the SELECT statement, holding the records “for your changes only” as you move through the rows retrieved by the cursor. It’s as if you’ve issued an UPDATE statement against the rows, but you haven’t—you’ve merely SELECTed them. No one else will be able to change any of these records until you perform a ROLLBACK or a COMMIT—but other sessions can still read the data.*
>
> **Ref: Oracle PL-SQL by O’Reilly, Pg 492**

However, I was also tracking down a couple other more complex but promising solutions. I never reached conclusion, but in the hopes that these are useful pointers for others, here they are.

1. **Oracle Package/CF Stored Procedure**: See section titled “[Use Oracle referenced cursors to return result sets (ColdFusion 4.5+, Oracle 7.3+)](http://www.orafusion.com/oracf_pls.htm):” and “Oracle PL-SQL” (Chapter 18 on Packages). I just hadn't figured out how to create the package and link it to CF, but this seemed like it would definitely be a viable solution.
2. I was going to test to see if CFTRANSACTION puts a lock on a record, which would be similar to my SELECT...FOR UPDATE solution above.